# SML-NJ, how to compile standalone executable

Tags: sml, smlnj

I start to learn Standard ML, and now I try to use Standard ML of New Jersey compiler.

Now I can use interactive loop, but how I can compile source file to standalone executable?

In C, for example, one can just write

`$ gcc hello_world.c -o helloworld`

and then run helloworld binary.

I read documentation for SML NJ Compilation Manager, but it don`t have any clear examples.

Also, is there another SML compiler (which allow standalone binary creating) available?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Both [MosML](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/mosml.html) and [MLton](http://mlton.org/) also have the posibility to create standalone binary files. MosML through mosmlc command and MLton through the mlton command.

Note that MLton doesn't have an interactive loop but is a whole-program optimising compiler. Which in basic means that it takes quite some time to compile but in turn it generates [incredibly fast](http://mlton.org/Performance) SML programs.

For SML/NJ you can use the `CM.mk_standalone` function, but this is not advised in the CM User Manual page 45. Instead they recommend that you use the ml-build command. This will generate a SML/NJ heap image. The heap image must be run with the @SMLload parameter, or you can use the [heap2exec](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/heap2exec/index.html) program, granted that you have a supported system. If you don't then I would suggest that you use MLton instead.

The following can be used to generate a valid SML/NJ heap image:

test.cm:

```
Group is 
        test.sml

        $/basis.cm
```

test.sml:

```
structure Test =
struct

fun main (prog_name, args) =
    let
      val _ = print ("Program name: " ^ prog_name ^ "\n")
      val _ = print "Arguments:\n"
      val _ = map (fn s => print ("\t" ^ s ^ "\n")) args
    in
      1
    end
end
```

And to generate the heap image you can use: `ml-build test.cm Test.main test-image` and then run it by `sml @SMLload test-image.XXXXX arg1 arg2 "this is one argument"` where XXXXX is your architecture.

If you decide to MLton at some point, then you don't need to have any main function. It evaluates everything at toplevel, so you can create a main function and have it called by something like this:

```
fun main () = print "this is the main function\n"

val foo = 4

val _ = print ((Int.toString 4) ^ "\n")

val _ = main ()
```

Then you can compile it by `mlton foo.sml` which will produce an executable named "foo". When you run it, it will produce this as result:

```
./foo 
4
this is the main function
```

Note that this is only one file, when you have multiple files you will either need to use MLB (ML  Basis files) which is MLtons project files or you can use cm files and then compile it by `mlton projectr.mlb`

Comment: Thank you, this helpful. Unfortunately, all "getting started" manuals that I found don't have simple examples to compile, assume to use top-level loop instead.

Comment: sorry，I build fail on Windows with error： can't find `XYZ_XXX_BOOTLIST`

Comment: Today it does not work more: `XYZ_XXX_smlfile.sml:1.38-1.84 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]                   operator domain: string * (string * string list -> OS.Process.status)                                   operand:         string * (string * string list -> int)`