# SML Connect's a command line arg input stream

Tags: command-line-arguments, sml

I am searching a way in SML to open a txt file whose name will be given by the user.

like in C where arv [1] is the user's filename of file.

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
   FILE * fp; 
   fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
   ...........
   ...........
}
```

Comment: Maybe not quite a duplicate (since you didn't specify SML/NJ) but see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078203/sml-connects-a-command-line-arg-input-stream

Comment: Could please post again the link ( It returns me to my question). I refer to SML/NJ.

Comment: Here is the correct link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19363314/4996248

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.