# Text editor and compiler for SML

Tags: sml

**Which text editor and compiler should we use to write and execute our programs respectively ?**
I am a complete beginner who hasn't got his hands quite dirty in programming .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile SML using SMLNJ while the code is in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125649/how-to-compile-sml-using-smlnj-while-the-code-is-in-notepad)

Comment: It was my first day in SML how could I have gone this far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write code in whatever editor you like, it has no impact on compilation.

To compile SML you have several choices (not limited to):

- [SMLNJ](https://www.smlnj.org/)
- Visual Studio (see [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=freebroccolo.sml))